# Regex to match anything but two words

Tags: .net, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match anything that isn't "foo" and "bar".  I found how to match anything but one word at [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) but I'm not very skilled with regex and am unsure of how to add a second word to this critera.

Any help would be most appreciated!

CLARIFICATION:

I wanted to match on anything that wasn't EXACTLY foo or bar.

Comment: is that anything that isn't "foo" or "bar"? Or anything that doesn't contain BOTH "foo" and "bar"?

Comment: How do you want to deal with strings that *contain* one of those two words, along with other characters? For example, should `blah blah foo blah blah` be allowed?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

**Answer to the question: "A Regular Expression to match anything that isn't "foo" and "bar"?"**

```
^(?!foo$|bar$).*
```

would do exactly that.

```
^      # Start of string
(?!    # Assert that it's impossible to match...
 foo   # foo, followed by
 $     # end of string
|      #
 bar$  # bar, followed by end of string.
)      # End of negative lookahead assertion
.*     # Now match anything
```

You might need to set `RegexOptions.Singleline` if your string can contain newlines that you also wish to match.

Comment: This would only fire if the entire string was one of the words. It's not clear whether the OP wants that or not, but it's worth pointing out.

Comment: A great answer to the first "part" of the question: "A regular expression to match anything that is not foo and bar."

Answer (score 37):

**Answer to the question: "How to add a second word to [this critera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)?"**

The answer of the question you link to is:

```
^((?!word).)*$
```

Where `(?!word)` is a negative look-ahead. The answer for this question is:

```
^((?!wordone|wordtwo).)*$
```

Works for both words. Note: you should enable the *global* and *multiline* options, if you have multiple lines and want to match for each line, as the other question.

The difference is the negative look-ahead clause: `(?!wordone|wordtwo)`. It can be extended to any (reasonable) amount of words or clauses.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word/406408#406408) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: This would fail to match `foonly` or `bartender` (or even any word that just contains `foo` or `bar`) which is not what goombaloon wants.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: different interpretation. If he meant to extend the answer of the question he refers to, then this works: it will not match anything that contains "foo" or "bar" or both.

Answer (score 13):

I get what you want to do, but the *specifics* of what you want to block/allow are a little unclear. For example, do you want to block anything that isn't **exactly** `foo` or `bar`? Or do you want to block anything **containing** those two strings?

Can they be part of another string, as in @Tim's `foonly` or `bartender` examples?

I'm just going to suggest patterns for each one:

```
/^(?!foo$|bar$).*/   #credit to @Tim Pietzcker for this one, he did it first
    #blocks "foo"
    #blocks "bar"
    #allows "hello goodbye"
    #allows "hello foo goodbye"
    #allows "foogle"
    #allows "foobar"

/^(?!.*foo|.*bar).*$/
    #blocks "foo"
    #blocks "bar"
    #allows "hello goodbye"
    #blocks "hello foo goodbye"
    #blocks "foogle"
    #blocks "foobar"

/^(?!.*\b(foo|bar)\b).*$/
    #blocks "foo"
    #blocks "bar"
    #allows "hello goodbye"
    #blocks "hello foo goodbye"
    #allows "foogle"
    #allows "foobar"
```