# Clear all except for a few specific variables in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

I'm aware of the `%reset` and `%reset_selective` commands in `IPython`. However, let's say you have many variables and you want to clear all variables except `x`, `y`, `z`. Is there a concise way to accomplish this?
Say a `%reset_all_except x,y,z`?

Comment: There isn't, but you could [define your own magic command](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/custommagics.html#defining-magics).

Answer (score 2):

this is a collective answer based off a ton of similar questions:

capture default variables in the system AND the name of the list that will save the variables to be preserved (should be your very first lines of code):

```
save_list = dir()
save_list.append('save_list') #thanks @V.Foy!
```

add other variables you want to save to the list before the "clear variables" command is used:

```
save_list.append(*your_variable_to_be_saved*)
```

finally, clear all variables (except default and saved) with:

```
for name in dir():
    if name not in save_list:
        del globals()[name]

for name in dir():
    if name not in save_list:
        del locals()[name]
```

this will clear all variables except the default and those you choose to save. whenever i did that without saving default variables, it cleared those too and i had to restart kernel to get them back.

Comment: Cool stuff! Maybe obvious to you guys but one should also add `save_list.append('save_list')` to avoid error. :)

Comment: now that you mention it, it seems really silly that I didn't include that in the answer. Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

`%reset_selective` accepts RegEx.
If you have variables named as: `glob_x, glob_y, glob_z` which you don't want to reset, you can use: `%reset_selective -f ^(?!glob_).*$`

Comment: Works like a charm! For further clarification of what the regex syntax means here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6830819/7382307