# ASP.NET Regular Expression - Dont allow website url

Tags: asp.net, validation, bootstrap-4

I am using ASP.net 4.5 with bootstrap.
Below is the code I have to allow only certain characters. 
How can I change this to allow the characters **a-zA-Z0-9_. /,&|()!-** but not allow the user to put in **http** or **www.**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Enter subject"
                                    data-bv-message="The subject is not valid."
                                    data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="The subject is required and cannot be empty."
                                    data-bv-regexp="true" data-bv-regexp-regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9_. /,&|()!-]+$" data-bv-regexp-message="The subject can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore."
                                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you might have to add groups for the words you don't want to have in your input value.

```
((!|www)|(!|http))
```

You can also take a look at this [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830796/regex-to-match-anything-but-two-words#answer-6830819), there you should get enough input to fix your expression

Comment: Thanks, but how would I add it to this? data-bv-regexp-regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9_. /,&|()!-]+$"